# Uploading image with vuejs frontend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, element

I'd like to implement uploading a profile picture for users. I'm using a VueJs frontend with a Rails API. What I'm trying to do is upload the image only using the frontend. I'd like for the file to get uploaded without any calls API calls. I could then store the location of the file in the picture attribute in the backend and retrieve it. Is that possible? I'm also using Element library.

````
   <el-upload :http-request="addAttachment">
        <el-button size="small" type="primary">Click Upload</el-button>
   </el-upload>```
````

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is called,

> **direct uploads or browser based uploads.**

There should be support from storage service you are using.

Example: using S3 and GCS it is possible.

Upload without any API calls? -
Not sure, I once had to make a small API call to get the signature key and use it with POST params to upload file to storage service(GCS)

Once the API response is returned, you then might want to write to db about the file path.